# How do I boot Alternate OS on every boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have done dual boot in my laptop. My Ubuntu is on 0 and Windows is on 2. I have updated following settings in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and in `/etc/grub.d/00_header` I have changed these lines:

```
if [ "x${GRUB_DEFAULT}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_DEFAULT=0 ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_DEFAULT}" = "xsaved" ] ; then GRUB_DEFAULT='$(expr ${saved_entry} % 4)'
 '{saved_entry}'='$(expr ${saved_entry} + 2)' ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_TIMEOUT}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_TIMEOUT=5 ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=auto ; fi

if [ "x${GRUB_DEFAULT_BUTTON}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_DEFAULT_BUTTON="$GRUB_DEFAULT" ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_DEFAULT_BUTTON}" = "xsaved" ] ; then GRUB_DEFAULT_BUTTON='$(expr ${saved_entry} % 4)' ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_TIMEOUT_BUTTON}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_TIMEOUT_BUTTON="$GRUB_TIMEOUT" ; fi
```

but its throwing error as follows:

```
/etc/grub.d/00_header: 41: {saved_entry}=$(expr ${saved_entry} + 2): not found
```

What could be the solution so that `${saved_entry}` is incremented by 2 in every boot?
Also after reaching at 50 i want it to reset to 0